# TracJSGanttChart throws errors

Tags: trac, gantt-chart

If I do not add the right custom ticket fields, TracJSGanttChart throws an error instead of rendering the chart.

I tried to solve this by adding *userstart* and *userfinish*. But it still crashes with the following error message: *complete is not a custom ticket field*

So there seem to be more fields necessary. Is there a sample *trac.ini* somewhere so that I can just copy the missing fields from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the gantt renderer is asking for start, end and (percent) completed here.

Shouldn't be too hard to add yet another custom field *complete* and make it fly. You're welcome to file a defect, or better an enhancement ticket for [TracJsGanttPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracJsGanttPlugin) for requesting a simple-start receipt, because current configuration hints seem rather complicated indeed.

Comment: Thanks, I expected more fields, so I gave up after adding _userstart_ and _userfinish_.